# Custom helper with block

Tags: erb, middleman, tilt, middleman-4

I'm using the current release 4.3.3 of Middleman.

I'd like to define a custom helper which accepts a block. For the sake of simplicity, here's a nonsensical example of `wrap_me` which wraps the block content with the given tag.

It should be possible to implement this with [`capture_html` provided by Padrino](http://padrinorb.com/guides/application-helpers/output-helpers) (which is explicitly mentioned in the Middleman docs):

```
module CustomHelpers
  def wrap_me(tag, &block)
    captured = capture_html(&block)
    concat_content "<#{tag}>" + captured + "</#{tag}>"
  end
end
```

Put to use in ERB:

```
<%= wrap_me('span') do %>
  Hello
<% end %>
```

Now this raises a SyntaxError on line 274 of tilt-2.0.9/lib/tilt/template.rb which tries to eval a string. It appears, the capture is going beyond the "end".

What am I doing wrong here? How to use `capture_html` and `concat_content` if Tilt is preventing helpers from having blocks?

Thanks for your help!

(I'll ask the same question in the [Middleman forum](https://forum.middlemanapp.com/t/custom-helper-with-block/3844).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, when using blocks, the equal sign has to be dropped. The following works:

```
<% wrap_me('span') do %>
  Hello
<% end %>
```

Comment: Funny enough, with slim, the equal sign works just fine.